# Disable SharePoint "Search Config" site featurss

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

I am working on a SharePoint communication site, and i found that those 4 "Search Config" site features are enabled:-

[image]

so is it fine to disable them, as seems they were enabled by mistake by the admin

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

None of these features required to be activated to perform the Search on the Site. Search will work without these.

These features used when you want to import /export the search configuration from /to another site collection.